# kubectl -o go-template > bad character U+002F '/'

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, go-templates

I'm trying to get the restartCount of the pod for matching deployment but '/' causing an issue

**Query:**  `kubectl -n <namespace> get pod -o go-template='{{range .items}}{{if eq .metadata.labels.app.kubernetes.io/name "my-app"}}{{ (index .status.containerStatuses 0).restartCount}}{{end}}{{end}}'`

**Error**: `template: output:1: bad character U+002F '/'`

I tried with the 'index' but did not help. Also tried adding quotes, escaping the special character '/' but no luck.

Any help is really appreciable. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the test

```
if eq .metadata.labels.app.kubernetes.io/name "my-app"
```

the `/` character isn't allowed in the [Go text/template](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) syntax.  You are probably looking for an object like

```yaml
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: my-app
```

and `.` also has special syntax here: it will look up `metadata`, `labels`, and then a single level `app` within that and so on.

The standard `index` function will let you use an arbitrary string as a map index (in other contexts, including a computed value, or an integer for an array index) and that's probably what you need here

```
if eq (index .metadata.labels "app.kubernetes.io/name") "my-app"
```